# Symfony2: How can I choose the environment to use when running unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I need to run unit tests for a Symfony2 application against two different DB configurations, one using a MySQL database and the other using a SQLite database.

I currently choose the DB configuration to use when running unit tests by editing `app/config/config_test.yml`. I either uncomment the MySQL-related db settings and comment-out the SQLite-related db settings or vice versa.

I'd like to not have to do this and to instead have two configuration files - perhaps `app/config/config-test-mysql.yml` and `app/config/config-test-sqlite.yml` - and choose the test environment from the command line when the tests are run.

Having looked at the default Symfony2 phpunit config in `app/phpunit.xml.dist` and having looked at the bootstrap file that config utilises (`app/bootstrap.php.cache`), I cannot determine how the environment defaults to `test` when running unit tests.

**How can I choose the environment to use when running unit tests?**

Comment: When will people stop relating to tests involving a database as **unit** tests?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this solution but I am sure this is a good lead.

My unit test class extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase` which enables you to create a `Client` which itself creates a `Kernel`.

In your unit test, you could do this:

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DatabaseRelatedTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private static $client;

    public function setUp()
    {
        // this is the part that should make things work
        $options = array(
            'environment' => 'test_mysql'
        );
        self::$client = static::createClient($options);
        self::$client->request('GET', '/foo/bar'); // must be a valid url
    }
}
```

You will be able to access the `EntityManager` and by extension the `Connection` using the container of the client.

```php
self::$client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')
```

The ideal would be to pass the environment's name to the `setUp` method using the `phpunit.xml.dist` file. It's probably a half-answer but I believe it's a good lead.

Comment: That looks like a good start. I'll give it a go over the next couple of days.